# Would using a foreign key help me in this example?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm confused about how to pull in related information from two different tables.
If I go to localhost:8000/user/username, it should display the users profile and user reviews below. because the username is being passed through the URL into the views function.  Is that correct?

Also, is it required that I use foreign key to accomplish this?  I've read the docs and I'm still not completely sure how a foreign key would help me accomplish my goal here.

## Models

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    reviewer = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.TextField()
    zipcode = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class UserReview(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    stars = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

## Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render 

def index(request):
    profile_info = User.objects.filter(name=username)
    context = {‘profile_info’: profile_info}    
    latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.filter(name=username).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {‘profile_info’: profile_info, 'latest_reviews': latest_reviews}
    return render(request, 'randomtemplate.html', context)
```

## URLS

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/', 'index'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things you need to do. The first is that you need to pass the parameter into the view function, and then you'll need to display the ratings in the template.

```
#view
def index(request, username):
    profile_info = User.objects.filter(name=username)
    latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.filter(name=username).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {‘profile_info’: profile_info, 'latest_reviews': latest_reviews}
    return render(request, 'randomtemplate.html', context)

# randomtemplate.html
{{ username }}
{{ latest_reviews }}
```